# Where does Visual Studio automatically install the Azure Functions CLI (Core Tools) for local debugging?

Tags: azure-functions

In Visual Studio when you start debugging an Azure Function locally, it downloads/installs the Azure Functions CLI (aka Azure Functions Core Tools). It does this automatically, what is doing it and where does it store it? I believe it is only doing this once. Not sure how updates occur.

Comment: why do you nedd this information for ?

Comment: Because when attempting to run locally the cli reported missing (couldn’t find or couldn’t find matching version) assembly which appears to part of the cli tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, it is this folder:
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\`

Example runtime folder for version 2.43.0, 64-bit:
`C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.43.0\cli_x64`

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is for Visual Studio, but the core tools CLI installer uses the following location:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\`